# Как передать данные в json файл при нажатии на кнопку в другой файл

Tags: javascript

Сейчас оно заменяет данные в name.json(полностью его стирает и добавляет новое) и как то не так, а нужно их добавить.

есть json файл name.json

```
[// это файл name.json 
    {
        "Name": "vasya",
        "lastName": "vasev",

    },
    {
        "Name": "micha",
        "lastName": "misckin",

    },

]
```

как в него добавить новую строчку

```
{
            "Name": "liza",
            "lastName": "lizkin",

        }
```

с помощью кнопки в другом файле, добавить информацию в файл name.json

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector('.load1');


button1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log(e);
  //e.prevennewwtDefault();
  


  var arr = {
  "Name": "liza",
  "lastName": "lizkin",
};
  var aaa = JSON.stringify(arr);
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {myJson:  arr , fileName: 'data.json'},
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    }
});
  })
  
   button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    
  e.preventDefault();
  
    fetch('data.json')
    .then(function(data){
   
      return data.json();
    
    })
    .then(function(data){
      text.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(data.text);
  
  
    })
  })
```

```html
<button class="load1">загрузить данные</button>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

и сам сервер

```
<?php
file_put_contents(  $_POST['fileName'], $_POST['myJson']);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю на сервере сделать так:

```
<?php
    $current_content = json_decode(file_get_contents($_POST['fileName'], true));
    array_push($current_content, $_POST["myJson"]);
    file_put_contents($_POST['fileName'], json_encode($current_content));
?>
```

Comment: выдает <!--error--><br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in <b>Z:\home\mys\www\data.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>

Comment: Поправил, скобку забыл

Comment: норм работает, а можешь еще подсказать, файл оно обновляет , а если нажать вывести информацию с файла оно показывает старую, хотя в файл информация добавилась?

Comment: Чтобы переменная `$current_content` обновилась и в ней было новое содержимое файла, используй строку кода моего ответа, где объявляется переменная. Либо я не понял твоего вопроса.

Comment: все спасибо, это проблемы были денвера